# How to get parent "node" based on property or name of a descendant node using XPath or SQL@ query?

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

I am writing a standalone program to get all the page nodes which have a certain descendant node. Ex - if structure is like this -

```
- parent
   - jcr:content
      -node1
      -node2
      -node3
         -node4
```

I want the parent node based on condition that name of node 4 is "test".

I have written the following query -

```sql
SELECT parent.* 
FROM [cq:Page] AS parent 
     INNER JOIN [cq:PageContent] AS child ON
         ISCHILDNODE(child, parent) 
     INNER JOIN [nt:unstructured] AS scndchild ON 
         ISDESCENDANTNODE(scndchild, child) 
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, '/content/folder/en') AND
      LOCALNAME(scndchild) LIKE '%test%' AND
      scndchild.[sling:resourceType] = 'something'
```

This query works fine in CRXde, but when I run it through Eclipse, the query returns 0 nodes.

Do I need to add something or do it differently in Eclipse?
Is there a way to write a nested query? Or an equivalent XPath query?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a suggestion and not an answer, instead of trying to write nested queries why not get the page using the PageManager API's `getContainingPage(resource)` method by passing the resource from your query result?